# Getting JSON code from Styled Maps Wizard to Integrate into Google Maps API html?

Tags: html, json, api, google-maps

I used the styled maps wizard to create a styled version of my google maps, but I am not sure how to integrate the JSON into my html? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here's a clip of the code.

```
{
"featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
]
}
```

Also, here's the [link to the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caseymmiller/yhexV/).

Here's all of my current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    height: 100%
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 100%
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoiYR3lgzcF8CxuOwe7SYsJAPjZQXOhQQ&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var line;
  var title;
  var map;
  var loc;
  var locations = [];
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('parkingIconRed.png');

  var styles = [
  {
"featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
    ]
  },{
"featureType": "road.local",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#80d9ff" },
  { "weight": 1.6 }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#d2d3ff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#ffffff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "landscape.man_made",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
  { "weight": 0.1 },
  { "color": "#f3f6f7" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#b4b4ff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#ffffff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "poi.school",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#f1f1f1" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "landscape.man_made",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" },
  { "weight": 3.2 }
]
  },{
"featureType": "administrative",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
]
  },{
  },{
  }
  ]
map.setOptions({styles: styles});


  function initialize() {
    var raleigh = new google.maps.LatLng(35.77425, -78.639248);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom : 17,
      minZoom : 17,
      center : raleigh,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    var cityPlaza;

    /*var RLINELayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://caseymmiller.com/j586/MapsTest/RLINE.kml');
     RLINELayer.setMap(map);*/

    var plazaCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.773893, -78.63854),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.772944, -78.638594),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.772962, -78.639345),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.773884, -78.63928)
    ];

    cityPlaza = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths : plazaCoords,
      strokeColor : "#33CCFF",
      strokeOpacity : 0.8,
      strokeWeight : 2,
      fillColor : "#33CCFF",
      fillOpacity : 0.35
    });
    cityPlaza.setMap(map);

    var parking = [
      ['Salisbury Deck', 35.775007, -78.640804],
      ['Cabarrus Deck', 35.774589, -78.640793],
      ['Hannover Deck', 35.774511, -78.640031],
      ['Convention Center Underground Deck', 35.773292, -78.639355],
      ['Performing Arts Deck', 35.772666, -78.641576],
      ['Charter Square Deck', 35.773893, -78.638551],
      ['Blount Street Deck', 35.776226, -78.637499],
      ['McDowell Street Surface Parking', 35.775303, -78.641673],
      ['Salisbury Parking Lot', 35.775442, -78.640814],
      ['Convention Center Parking Lot', 35.772553, -78.639527],
      ['Lenoir Street Parking Lot', 35.773231, -78.638207],
      ['Carrabus street Parking Lot', 35.774032, -78.63824]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < parking.length; i++) {
      createMarker(parking[i]);
    }

    var lineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.779742, -78.643389), new google.maps.LatLng(35.77438, -78.643733), new google.maps.LatLng(35.774259, -78.640396), new google.maps.LatLng(35.772953, -78.640482), new google.maps.LatLng(35.772866, -78.638465), new google.maps.LatLng(35.776879, -78.638315), new google.maps.LatLng(35.776766, -78.634989), new google.maps.LatLng(35.778097, -78.634883), new google.maps.LatLng(35.778202, -78.638209), new google.maps.LatLng(35.781178, -78.638059)];

    var lineSymbol = {
      path : google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale : 8,
      strokeColor : '#000'
    };

    line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path : lineCoordinates,
      strokeColor : '#C82536',
      icons : [{
        icon : lineSymbol,
        offset : '100%'
      }],
      map : map
    });
    animateCircle();
  }

  function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    var time = offsetId = window.setInterval(function() {
      count = (count + 1) % 2400;

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 24) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
  }

  function createMarker(parking) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parking[1], parking[2]);
    console.log(myLatLng.toUrlValue());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : myLatLng,
      map : map,
      icon : image, 
      title: parking[0],
    });
    return marker;
  }



</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
</html>​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently setting the new style map option before the map is initialized which won't work ...

So either put the setOptions line after your "map = ... " line, or you can just include the styles in your existing mapOptions object:

```
var mapOptions = {
  zoom : 17,
  styles: styles,
  minZoom : 17,
  center : raleigh,
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=en)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    height: 100%
  }
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }
  #map_canvas {
    height: 100%
  }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoiYR3lgzcF8CxuOwe7SYsJAPjZQXOhQQ&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var line;
  var title;
  var map;
  var loc;
  var locations = [];
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('parkingIconRed.png');

  var styles = [
  {
"featureType": "road.highway.controlled_access",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
    ]
  },{
"featureType": "road.local",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#80d9ff" },
  { "weight": 1.6 }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#d2d3ff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.arterial",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#ffffff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "landscape.man_made",
"elementType": "geometry.fill",
"stylers": [
  { "weight": 0.1 },
  { "color": "#f3f6f7" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#b4b4ff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#ffffff" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "road.highway",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "poi.school",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#f1f1f1" }
]
  },{
"featureType": "landscape.man_made",
"elementType": "geometry.stroke",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" },
  { "weight": 3.2 }
]
  },{
"featureType": "administrative",
"stylers": [
  { "color": "#808080" }
]
  },{
  },{
  }
  ]


  function initialize() {
    var raleigh = new google.maps.LatLng(35.77425, -78.639248);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom : 17,
      minZoom : 17,
      center : raleigh,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      styles: styles
    }



    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    var cityPlaza;

    /*var RLINELayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://caseymmiller.com/j586/MapsTest/RLINE.kml');
     RLINELayer.setMap(map);*/

    var plazaCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.773893, -78.63854),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.772944, -78.638594),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.772962, -78.639345),
      new google.maps.LatLng(35.773884, -78.63928)
    ];

    cityPlaza = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths : plazaCoords,
      strokeColor : "#33CCFF",
      strokeOpacity : 0.8,
      strokeWeight : 2,
      fillColor : "#33CCFF",
      fillOpacity : 0.35
    });
    cityPlaza.setMap(map);

    var parking = [
      ['Salisbury Deck', 35.775007, -78.640804],
      ['Cabarrus Deck', 35.774589, -78.640793],
      ['Hannover Deck', 35.774511, -78.640031],
      ['Convention Center Underground Deck', 35.773292, -78.639355],
      ['Performing Arts Deck', 35.772666, -78.641576],
      ['Charter Square Deck', 35.773893, -78.638551],
      ['Blount Street Deck', 35.776226, -78.637499],
      ['McDowell Street Surface Parking', 35.775303, -78.641673],
      ['Salisbury Parking Lot', 35.775442, -78.640814],
      ['Convention Center Parking Lot', 35.772553, -78.639527],
      ['Lenoir Street Parking Lot', 35.773231, -78.638207],
      ['Carrabus street Parking Lot', 35.774032, -78.63824]
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < parking.length; i++) {
      createMarker(parking[i]);
    }

    var lineCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(35.779742, -78.643389), new google.maps.LatLng(35.77438, -78.643733), new google.maps.LatLng(35.774259, -78.640396), new google.maps.LatLng(35.772953, -78.640482), new google.maps.LatLng(35.772866, -78.638465), new google.maps.LatLng(35.776879, -78.638315), new google.maps.LatLng(35.776766, -78.634989), new google.maps.LatLng(35.778097, -78.634883), new google.maps.LatLng(35.778202, -78.638209), new google.maps.LatLng(35.781178, -78.638059)];

    var lineSymbol = {
      path : google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
      scale : 8,
      strokeColor : '#000'
    };

    line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path : lineCoordinates,
      strokeColor : '#C82536',
      icons : [{
        icon : lineSymbol,
        offset : '100%'
      }],
      map : map
    });
    animateCircle();
  }

  function animateCircle() {
    var count = 0;
    var time = offsetId = window.setInterval(function() {
      count = (count + 1) % 2400;

      var icons = line.get('icons');
      icons[0].offset = (count / 24) + '%';
      line.set('icons', icons);
    }, 20);
  }

  function createMarker(parking) {
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parking[1], parking[2]);
    console.log(myLatLng.toUrlValue());
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position : myLatLng,
      map : map,
      icon : image, 
      title: parking[0],
    });
    return marker;
  }



</script>
 </head>
 <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @user1855009 I have edited the code. Does this make sense now?

Comment: I know this isn't right, but I really don't know what to do. This is what I have right now. - I included all of my current code in an edit above.

Comment: @user1855009 I have changed the code again. You must put this into your initialize action with the list of all options.